# c#: Project Euler 8. Have some troubles in program

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program to solve problem 8 in project Euler, which finds the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. Firstly, i determine that the 1000-digit number is a string. Then i create a split method that        breaks up this string into smaller chars, and converts it to int number. (i use ulong type instead of int)

```
static ulong split(char input)
        {
            ulong number = ulong.Parse(Convert.ToString(input));
            return number;
        }
```

then i create a method that has ability to check whether what is the biggest product. convert it into int type, find the product of thirteen adjacent digits.

```
static ulong check(string string1)
        {
            ulong product = 1;
            ulong max = 0;
            ulong[] array = new ulong[50];

            char[] h1 = string1.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < string1.Length; i++)
               array[i] = split(h1[i]);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 12; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
                {
                    product *= array[i + j]
                    if (product > max)
                        max = product;
                }
                product = 1;
            }
            return max;
```

In the main method. i write some code to input the 1000-digit number and write the answer.

```
 string input =               @"73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
                             96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
                             85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
                             12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
                             66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
                             62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
                             30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
                             70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
                             65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
                             52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
                             53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
                             83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
                             82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
                             16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
                             17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
                             24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
                             07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
                             84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
                             05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
                             71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
            input = input.Replace("  ", "");
            input = input.Replace("/r/n", "");
            Console.Write(check(input));
            Console.ReadKey();
```

But the program has trouble in the split method. can you explain for me, please ? :(
here is all my program.

```
string input = @"73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
                             96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
                             85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
                             12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
                             66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
                             62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
                             30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
                             70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
                             65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
                             52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
                             53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
                             83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
                             82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
                             16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
                             17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
                             24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
                             07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
                             84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
                             05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
                             71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
            input = input.Replace("  ", "");
            input = input.Replace("/r/n", "");
            Console.Write(check(input));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static ulong split(char input)
        {
            ulong number = ulong.Parse(Convert.ToString(input));
            return number;
        }
        static ulong check(string string1)
        {
            ulong product = 1;
            ulong max = 0;
            ulong[] array = new ulong[50];

            char[] h1 = string1.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < string1.Length; i++)
               array[i] = split(h1[i]);
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 12; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
                {
                    product *= array[i + j];

                    if (product > max)
                    {
                        max = product;
                        Console.Write(array[i + j] + "   ");
                    }
                }
                product = 1;
            }
            return max;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need all that splitting at all? It makes the program more inefficient.

Comment: You could use Char.GetNumericValue(char c) to save a few instructions  instead of converting to string to use the parse method

Comment: ok. thanks you very much, it make my code become more efficient :D